Does "limit 1" increase performance for unique-value column queries
Say I have a table in a sqlite database where the id column is marked UNIQUE (in my actual use case, it's the primary key).  Clearly, the query
select foo from some_table where id = 1

will return at most one row.  Is there any performance increase by appending limit 1 to the query or is sqlite smart enough to realize that no more rows can possibly match once it finds a single row?

It depends of the query optimizer and of the the optimizer depends of the RDBMS vendor...
In big RDBMS like Oracle or SQL Server, if the id has an UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint, the LIMIT 1  (wich does not exists in the standard ISO SQL) is remove because it is not necessary. When uniqueness is verified only 0 or 1 row can be returned so limiting to one row is not necessary. This is a classical semantic optimization.
The conclusion is that you can have it, but it is stupid. The performances will be the same... Better removing all unecessary code !
On poor RDBMS, like SQLite or MySQL this kind of optimization is not current, so the system will try to order the single row of the dataset...
This is one more operation causing extra execution. SO remove to avoid less performances!
By the way, LIMIT 1 is not standard but
ORDER BY ... OFFSET ... FETCH { PRIOR | NEXT } ... 

is !

Apparently even MySQL isn't that stupid https://dbfiddle.uk/mVWtVh6Q nor is SQLite https://dbfiddle.uk/OOLlu1TZ

@Charlieface impossible to prouve without a detailed execution plan...

I thought that's what I just gave you. For comparison without a primary key https://dbfiddle.uk/qc9CI-_y and https://dbfiddle.uk/zPY6UrlL you can see the sorts

@Charlieface the thing I see is that MySQL does a sort for 1 row.... So mySQL is stupid.... "Using filesort" in the query execution plan

@Charlieface : I see : "USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY" remember that a B-TREE is ordered ! So in the two query an order by is made on only one row.... Which is stupid, like the most part MySQL do...

@Charlieface it is in your fiddle... https://dbfiddle.uk/zPY6UrlL

I did not notice that the second plan was for SQlite... Your message was not clear enough. By the way, the EXPLAIN of MySQL is too "small" to see what is the method used to access the data... But I read "Using where; Using filesort" so MySQL does a sort for 1 row...
